# TLS 1.3 issue, use higher Docker image dotnet version or create security problem

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, ssl, .net-core

I have a legacy API dotnet core app, Linux docker.

Lately some HTTP Client calls throws

> System.Net.WebException: The SSL connection could not be established,
> see inner exception. The remote certificate is invalid according to
> the validation procedure.

Lovely SecurityProtocol saga, the root cause is the fact that dotnet core 2.1 / 2.2 doesn't have TLS 1.3.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.securityprotocoltype?view=net-5.0

So, my question is, what solution would you chose from the two ones I got? and if there's a better option, both 1 and 2 are tested.

Solution 1, higher dotnet core docker image (project remains on 2.1):

```
#replace FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
```

Solution 2, pass throw TLS certificate validation, (security concern)

```
 var handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>
                {
                    return true;
                }
            };

 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))

// or with named IHttpClientFactory
 services.AddHttpClient("insecure_tls")
                .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(_ => new HttpClientHandler
                {
                    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; }
                });

using (HttpClient client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("insecure_tls")
```

you got the idea, there are multiple ways to pass the tls validation.

**Repeating question, what solution would you chose to use, without updating project version? personally I would go with 1 for security concerns, but how would you approach this situation, and if there is any other option**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: .NET Core 2.1 is no longer supported, so the answer is easy - *upgrade* to either .NET Core 3.1 or wait a month to upgrade to the next LTS version, 6. Although .NET 6 RC1 is already supported in production

Comment: `without updating project version` why? Given that .NET Core 2.1 is unsupported and obviously doesn't support TLS1.2, why do you want to remain in that version?

Comment: I need time, I want to act now

Comment: So upgrade to 3.1

Comment: But only docker, project will be updated later

Comment: you recommend it?

Comment: Doing this will swap one set of known breaking changes for a set of unknown compatibility issues. If time is an issue, the migration should have started in time. The 3 year lifecycle of LTS releases was known from the start. There were [reminders as well](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-2-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-august-21-2021/)

Comment: `you recommend it` since you rejected the only safe recommendation, what option is there? All have issues but only one lets you run on a supported runtime. At least until [December 2022](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core), when 3.1 goes out of support. This will give you the time to properly migrate. I suspect there will be a few issues with EF Core, if you use it

Comment: I know, not doubting your logic, it will happen, asap, problem is that my issue must be fixed now, today, when the migration with all the approvals behind will take around 2 weeks. So again is it safe to assume increasing  docker image dotnet vision won't introduce any other problems.

Comment: Sorry, I miss read one of the previews comments, ok, I will go with code change and focus on overall project update with all the goods, nuget packages, debian pakages and so on, thank you.

Comment: At this point none of the options is great. You'll have to test your application and check whether it's affected by the [known breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/3.0), especially in ASP.NET Core. If your app is an ASP.NET Core app [it will have serious problems](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14458).